# Headless Install gets stuck at fsck

Tags: boot, fsck

I have been trying all of the tricks I have found to allow `fsck` to automatically fix errors without any user intervention however it seems that I can still get into this situation which is a major problem.

I've tried the following:

- `FSCKFIX=YES` in `/etc/init/rcS`
- added `fsck.fix=yes fsck.repair=yes` to `/etc/default/grub` (then run `update-grub`)

Unfortunately this is an embedded install that always get a hard power down.  I am currently able to force this failure mode by setting the clock ahead, doing a soft-reboot, then doing a hard reboot.  It will get stuck everytime when I do this...

It is not clear exactly where the fsck call that is failing is coming from, although I do see the error log in `/var/log/upstart/mountall.log`.

This is a rather specific failure mode, hopefully someone out there has some nugget of wisdom for me...

Thanks